# How to scrape a javascripted table of the fifa website

Tags: javascript, r, phantomjs, scrape

For a research project i would like to scrape all results of international football(soccer) games from the fifa website. I am using R to do this. However, it seems that the tables containing the matches are generated using javascript. 
This is the url I would like to scrape:

http://www.fifa.com/live-scores/international-tournaments/fixtures-results/index.html#month5-2018

I tried using phantomjs to render the page after the javascript table has been rendered but in the resulting html, the tables containing match results are still not given. This is my code:

```
    url = "http://www.fifa.com/live-scores/international- 
    tournaments/fixtures-results/index.html#month5-2018"

    writeLines(sprintf("
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = 'scrape.html'

    page.open('%s', function (status) {
      var content = page.content;
      fs.write(path, content, 'w')
      phantom.exit();
    });", url), con="scrape.js")

    system("./phantomjs.exe scrape.js")
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to crawl the table after it's is constructed, this website make some calls to some  endpoints like these.

http://data.fifa.com/livescores/en/internationaltournaments/matches/m/byyearandmonth/2018/5

http://data.fifa.com/livescores/live/matches

To find them use the network inspector on your brower (press f12). The easier way is to pick the jsons that construct these tables, instead of picking the tables after they were constructed.

edit: All the data that construct the tables are on these jsons, to get the data. first do a get request and download the content of the webpages that contains these  jsons. When you check the content of the webpage you'll see that the're jsons  but they're inside a function , just delete that.

For example in the first link you can delete `_matchesByYearAndMonthCallback(` and the last `)` , that are escaping the json.

After you delete that, you get a valid json that you can parse inside **R** with packages **json.lite** or **json**, check the documentation. after you use one of these packages you should get a dataframe, that you can pick the informations.

Example of the beggining of the json that you'll get.

```
{
"competitionslist": {
    "0": {
        "name": "Friendlies",
        "idCup": 506,
        "edition": 1872,
        "idCupSeason": 2000010101,
        "isFifaCompetition": true,
        "countryCode": "",
        "cupKindID": 105,
        "competitionSeoName": "friendly-506",
        "hasStanding": false,
        "linkMatches": "",
        "linkStanding": "",
        "link": "",
        "hasMatchLive": false,
        "isActiveSeason": true,
        "matchlist": [{
            "idCup": 506,
            "idCupSeason": 2000010101,
            "edition": 1872,
            "isLive": false,
            "isActiveSeason": true,
            "isFifaCompetition": true,
            "isClubCompetition": false,
            "competitionName": "Friendlies",
            "providerCompetitionID": 0,
            "providerEditionID": 0,
            "idMatch": 300438343,
            "internalMatchID": 0,
            "idRound": 281863,
            "idHomeTeam": 43818,
            "homeCountryCode": "IRQ",
            "homeTeamName": "Iraq",
            "idAwayTeam": 43989,
            "awayCountryCode": "PLE",
            "awayTeamName": "Palestine",
            "matchDate": "2018-05-08T16:00:00Z",
            "matchDateUTC": "2018-05-08T16:00:00Z",
            "kickOffTime": "16:00",
            "minute": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "cupKindID": 105,
            "cupKindName": "Friendly",
            "hasLineup": false,
            "scoreHome": 0,
            "scoreAway": 0,
            "venueName": "Basra ",
            "competitionSeoName": "friendly-506",
            "matchSeoName": "Iraq-Palestine-300438343",
            "homeTeamSeoName": "iraq-43818",
            "awayTeamSeoName": "palestine-43989",
            "hasStanding": false,
            "winTeamName": "",
            "winTeamShortName": "",
            "isStarted": true,
            "isFinished": true,
            "isAwarded": false,
            "isPostponed": false,
            "isSuspended": false,
            "isAbandoned": false,
            "link": "",
            "isNextDay": false
        }, {
            "idCup": 506,
            "idCupSeason": 2000010101,
            "edition": 1872,
            "isLive": false,
            "isActiveSeason": true,
            "isFifaCompetition": true,
            "isClubCompetition": false,
            "competitionName": "Friendlies",
            "providerCompetitionID": 0,
            "providerEditionID": 0,
            "idMatch": 300439349,
            "internalMatchID": 0,
            "idRound": 281863,
            "idHomeTeam": 43843,
            "homeCountryCode": "ALG",
            "homeTeamName": "Algeria",
            "idAwayTeam": 43835,
            "awayCountryCode": "KSA",
            "awayTeamName": "Saudi Arabia",
            "matchDate": "2018-05-09T19:30:00Z",
            "minute": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "cupKindID": 105,
            "cupKindName": "Friendly",
            "hasLineup": false,
            "scoreHome": 0,
            "scoreAway": 2,
            "venueName": "Cadiz ",
            "idWinTeam": 43835,
            "competitionSeoName": "friendly-506",
            "matchSeoName": "Algeria-Saudi Arabia-300439349",
            "homeTeamSeoName": "algeria-43843",
            "awayTeamSeoName": "saudi-arabia-43835",
            "hasStanding": false,
            "winTeamName": "Saudi Arabia",
            "winTeamShortName": "Saudi Arabia",
            "isStarted": true,
            "isFinished": true,
            "isAwarded": false,
            "isPostponed": false,
            "isSuspended": false,
            "isAbandoned": false,
            "link": "",
            "isNextDay": false
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it clarifies a lot! However, I don't really understand how I could pick the jsons that construct the tables?